# PyMC3 is much slower than PyMC in Metropolis sampling

Tags: bayesian, sampling, pymc3, pymc, mcmc

I am trying to compare the sampling speed between PyMC and PyMC3.

PyMC:

```
p1 = pymc.Normal('p1', 10, 0.5)
p2 = pymc.Gamma('p2', 11, 5)
p3 = pymc.Normal('p3', p1, p2)
model = pymc.Model([p1, p2, p3])

mcmc = pymc.MCMC(model)
mcmc.use_step_method(pymc.Metropolis, p1, p2, p3)
mcmc.sample(10000, progress_bar=True)
```

This took 2.7s

PyMC3:

```
with pm.Model() as model:
    p1 = pm.Normal('p1', 10, 0.5)
    p2 = pm.Gamma('p2', 11, 5)
    p3 = pm.Normal('p3', p1, p2)
    steps = pm.Metropolis(vars=[p1, p2, p3])
    trace = pm.sample(10000,step=steps, progressbar=True)
```

This took 6.6s

Is this normal? Am I missing some optimization tricks for PyMC3?

Comment: How are you measuring time? user time? CPU time? Are you measuring the whole script or just sampling time? The Theano compute graph, which PyMC3 uses, takes a non-trivial amount of time to initialize, and the range of difference you report could easily be explained by that. In large hierarchical models, I've seen initialization take upwards of 30 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I measured the user time using `%%time` function in jupyter. The graph initialization in PyMC3 took 1s (same code without `trace = pm.sample(10000,step=steps, progressbar=True)` ).

Comment: Could also be a difference in the defaults.  For example, looking at [the old settings](https://github.com/twiecki/pymc-1/blob/master/pymc/MCMC.py#L199), I think you would need to add arguments like `pm.sample(..., chains=1, tune=0)` and `pm.Metropolis(...,tune_interval=1000)` to mimic the old defaults.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal! PyMC3 is optimized for running NUTS, an MCMC algorithm for continuous models that is orders of magnitude more efficient than Metropolis for sampling from hierarchical models. Conversely, `pymc` is written in fortran, which provides some speedups over jitted theano code from pymc3, and perhaps cares more deeply about algorithms like Metropolis.